# R regex - match until first letter-space-digit combination from the end

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have the following string vector:

```
x = c("Breakfast Sandwich 12.6 - 18.4oz 4 - 8ct", 
      "Buffalo Wing 7.6 - 10 oz", 
      "Asstd Cafe Appetizer 8 - 20", 
      "16in Extra Lrg Pepperoni 45.5oz")
```

I need to move the size to the beginning of the string, but I can't create a proper `regex` call for it. If more than one combination is found, move only the last one. The part that is moved will always be preceded by a letter and space.
The desired output will be:

```
"4 - 8ct Breakfast Sandwich 12.6 - 18.4oz", 
"7.6 - 10 oz Buffalo Wing", 
"8 - 20 Asstd Cafe Appetizer", 
"45.5oz 16in Extra Lrg Pepperoni"
```

I think, non-greedy matching until something like `[a-z] [0-9].*?` is found? Or may be use `split` instead?
Could you, please, help me with it? Thank you in advance!

B.t.w., if there is no one step solution for all test cases, a series of separate `gsub` will work as well.

Comment: Yes. There could be units other than oz and ct, the rule is that only the last "chunk" is moved

Comment: Somebody go wake up akrun.

Comment: @RichardScriven, what happened to your answer? I was about to upvote it

Comment: I feel bad now. Even if it works for part of the cases, it is already great help for me

Comment: Great, thanks! Pls see edit about series of `gsub` if one is too complex or not even possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to handle the cases you mentioned:

`sub("(.*[a-z]{1}) ([0-9.]+\\s*-?\\s*[0-9.]*\\s*[a-z]*\\s*)$", "\\2 \\1", x)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 gsub('(.*(?<=\\w)) (\\d.*$)','\\2 \\1',x,perl=T)
[1] "4 - 8ct Breakfast Sandwich 12.6 - 18.4oz" "7.6 - 10 oz Buffalo Wing"                 "8 - 20 Asstd Cafe Appetizer"             
[4] "45.5oz 16in Extra Lrg Pepperoni"
```

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work for your cases too

```
sub("(.*[a-zA-Z]) +(\\d.*)", "\\2 \\1", x)
# [1] "4 - 8ct Breakfast Sandwich 12.6 - 18.4oz" "7.6 - 10 oz Buffalo Wing"                
# [3] "8 - 20 Asstd Cafe Appetizer"              "45.5oz 16in Extra Lrg Pepperoni"
```

Comment: Thank you too! I have multiple choice now :)

Comment: Why not go with the one with half the number of characters ;)